# reCAPTCHA + Ajax is never passing validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, recaptcha

I have this form:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
<label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
<input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellidos" required="" />
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="ejemplo@correo.com" required="" />
<label for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label>
<textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required=""></textarea>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXX"></div>
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
<span id="error-message" style="color: red;"></span>
```

With this php code for submission:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $secretkey = "XXXX";
    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretkey&response=$response&remoteip=$ip";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $row = json_decode($data, TRUE);
    
    if ($row['success'] == "true"){
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
        $para = 'my-email@gmail.com';
        $titulo = 'New contact form entry';
        $header = 'From: ' . $email;
        $msjCorreo = "Nombre: $nombre\n E-Mail: $email\n Mensaje:\n $mensaje";
        
        if (mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header)) {
        echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'message' => '¡Gracias por tu mensaje!']);
        } else {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'No ha sido posible enviar tu mensaje. Prueba a contactarme vía RRSS, ¡por favor!']);
        }
        
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Oops, you\'re a robot!']);
    }
    exit;
}
```

?>

And this ajax bit, as I want the page NOT to be refreshed if the user tries to submit the form without validating reCAPTCHA:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.attr('action');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: form.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        alert(response.message);
                        form.trigger('reset');
                    } else {
                        $('#error-message').text(response.message);
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#error-message').text('An error occurred. Please try again later.');
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Without the Ajax validation, the form works like a charm: will only submit the info if reCAPTCHA is validated and will reload the page otherwise. But the Ajax request is always returning "An error ocurred", even if I pass the reCAPTCHA. Any ideas on where I'm doing something wrong? Kinda lost at the moment. Thank you!

Comment: Use the Network tab of DevTools to see the actual response from the server.

Comment: @Barmar clicking into submit after passing reCAPTCHA only generates a new row with the following info: Name "contacto.php" Status "200" Type "xhr" Initiator "jquery.min.js:2" Size "2.3 kB" Time "70-90ms". No movements in the graphic on the top

Comment: What does that have to do with my suggestion? Use the network tab to see what is being sent when you submit the form, and what the reply is.

Comment: The error could be because there's a problem with the JSON being returned.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Barmar but unfortunately I'm not an expert in the matter and I can't understand anything of what I see in the Network tab...

Comment: We're not a tutoring service, I don't think I can walk you through how to debug web pages. Click on the line that posts to the PHP script, then click on the Response tab. There you should see the JSON. Notice whether there's anything before or after it, like error messages.